# Refresh Table Inside the JSF Fragment

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I know it's simple but I cannot seem to get it working I know how to use partial trigger but for some unknown reason I cannot seem to make it working. Well my question is this I have a `<af:table>` inside my jsf fragment(I used task flow for creating this fragment) and what I wanted to do is create a simple searching method using valuechangelistener on my textfield so the table will be search for every change that happen on the textfield well the problem is it seem that the `<af:table partialTrigger=":id of my textfield">` is not working it retain the old value in the table it is not refreshing or anything do you have any work around for this kind of problems. To make it clear I'll post some of my code.

JSF Fragment Page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1" inlineStyle="width: 900px;">
    <f:facet name="center">
      <af:panelGroupLayout layout="scroll" id="pgl3">
        <af:panelGridLayout id="pgl1">
          <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" marginBottom="5px" height="auto" id="gr1">
            <af:gridCell marginStart="10px" width="100px" id="gc1" halign="end" valign="middle">
              <af:outputLabel value="Search: " id="ol1" inlineStyle="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;"/>
            </af:gridCell>
            <af:gridCell marginStart="10px" width="250px" id="gc2" halign="start" valign="middle">
              <af:inputText label=" " valueChangeListener="#{personnelFragment.SearchRecords}" autoSubmit="true" columns="40" id="searchTxt"/>
            </af:gridCell>
            <af:gridCell marginStart="10px" width="100px" id="gc3" halign="end" valign="middle">
              <af:outputLabel value="Sort By: " id="ol2" inlineStyle="color:Black; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;"/>
            </af:gridCell>
            <af:gridCell marginStart="10px" marginEnd="5px" width="25%" id="gc4">
              <af:selectOneChoice label=" " id="soc1">
                <af:selectItem label="Firstname" id="si1"/>
                <af:selectItem label="Middlename" id="si2"/>
                <af:selectItem label="Lastname" id="si3"/>
              </af:selectOneChoice>
            </af:gridCell>
          </af:gridRow>
        </af:panelGridLayout>


        <af:table width="700px" partialTriggers=":searchTxt" id="t1" value="#{personnelFragment.personnelInfoData}" var="PersonnelData"
        horizontalGridVisible="true" verticalGridVisible="true" inlineStyle="margin: 10px 0 10px 0;"
        rowSelection="single">
            <af:column headerText="Prefix" align="center" id="c4">
                <af:outputLabel value="#{PersonnelData.prefix}" id="ol6"
                                inlineStyle="color:Black; font-size:10px;"/>
            </af:column>

            <af:column headerText="Firstname" align="center" id="c1">
                <af:outputLabel value="#{PersonnelData.firstName}" id="ol3"
                                inlineStyle="color:Black; font-size:10px;"/>
            </af:column>

            <af:column headerText="Middlename" align="center" id="c2">
                <af:outputLabel value="#{PersonnelData.middleName}" id="ol4"
                                inlineStyle="color:Black; font-size:10px;"/>
            </af:column>

            <af:column headerText="Lastname" align="center" id="c3">
                <af:outputLabel value="#{PersonnelData.lastName}" id="ol5"
                                inlineStyle="color:Black; font-size:10px;"/>
            </af:column>

            <af:column headerText="Suffix" align="center" id="c5">
                <af:outputLabel value="#{PersonnelData.suffix}" id="ol7"
                                inlineStyle="color:Black; font-size:10px;"/>
            </af:column>

            <af:column headerText=" " align="center" id="c6">
                <af:commandImageLink id="cil1" icon="#{resource['images:check.png']}" actionListener="#{personnelFragment.SearchPersonnelInfo}" />
            </af:column>
        </af:table>

  </af:panelGroupLayout>
</f:facet>
<f:facet name="top"/>
```

my Bean(Value Change Listener) but I'll just paste the important part:

```
        calState = (OracleCallableStatement)con.prepareCall("{ call SEARCH_PERSONNELINFO(?, ?) }");
    calState.setObject(1, e.getNewValue());
    calState.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    calState.execute();
    rs = (ResultSet)calState.getObject(2);
    while(rs.next()){
        PersonnelInfoData.add(new GetPersonnelData(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3),
                                rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6)));
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) +" "+ rs.getString(2));

    }
    calState.close();
```

I used store procedure this code is working I fine as you can see I print the sample result to the log and working just fine. my problem is just on refreshing the page.

1). does partialTrigger will only happen if there is a `<af:form>` tags?(Since the jsf fragment doesn't support `<af:form>`)
2) I search just a while ago and in some forums they create the trigger programmatically like this `AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(Component);` can you please explain to me what this code is for?
3) How can I refresh my table inside the jsf fragment?

Help and guidance will really appreciated.

Comment: You're not using [RichFaces](http://jboss.org/richfaces). You're using [Oracle ADF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html). I fixed the incorrect tagging.

Comment: thanks baluc and sorry for the late reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Try manually refreshing the table in your backing bean with a line like:
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(t1);

Comment: Well I already tried this code and it is not working. or perhaps I I have an error on my code I see this code on forums but I can't understand where do I put it? Should I put this code on the valuechangelistener code?

Answer (score 0):

1) The af:form tags are in the jsp/jspx page where you dropped your fragments/ taskflow (you can check it).
2) The same as the partialTrigger attribute but instead of ID, you use the binding defined in your bean.
3) Like you said, using partialTrigger="id of your component".

Since you are using a bean for displaying your data, you might want the check the caching on your iteraor (check the bindings, select you iterator, check the properties).